# Flutter - build release .exe with embedded dll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I'm tring to build a simple application in dart/flutter for windows. After `flutter build windows --release` it creates a .exe with all .dll files that application uses. Obviously when I copy and past the .exe in another folder the .exe does't work.
There are a way to embed .dll into the .exe?

Comment: Flutter itself does not provide something like that, you have to look for a third-party tool or such. Flutter doesn't even include in the release folder additional DLLs that might be needed by some packages.

Comment: Even if it is technically possible, it might not be legal (i.e., it might violate licensing terms).

Comment: You can use Inno Setup app to create windows installer. Follow this tutorial https://protocoderspoint.com/how-to-create-exe-installation-file-of-flutter-windows-application/